# Python - White space generated after closing plot matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

In mode `%matplotlib notebook`, when I try to close one figure, jupyter leaves white space into the notebook.

Is there one command to delete this white space or the correct way to close the figure ?

```
ma = [int(1000*random.random()) for i in xrange(10000)]

plt.figure()
counts,bins,bars = plt.hist(ma,200,alpha=0.5)
plt.close()

plt.figure()
plt.plot(ma)
```

[IMAGE EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypo8v.png)